# Browser support and workarounds for Turkish lira sign

Tags: html, unicode, turkish

So Turkey recently decided to create a new sign for their lira:

[image]

Unicode 6.2 (released September 2012) added this to [its repertoire](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf) as `U+20BA ₺ TURKISH LIRA SIGN`, and I've been asked to start using it in a web app I'm building.  The problem is that *nobody* supports this yet (except apparently Windows 8), and it's not showing up as the usual square, question mark or block o' hex, but all sorts of other random things.  The usually reliable [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ba/index.htm) thinks it's supposed to look like this:

[image]

...which is also what I get on OS X.  [Charbase](http://www.charbase.com/20ba-unicode-invalid-character) gets it wrong too, but differently:

[image]

The practical question: Is there any sensible way to work around this?  The largest complication is that the character is supposed to be allowed in arbitrary, user-editable text, so any image-based solutions are out the window.

And the theoretical question: as far as I can see, U+20BA has never had a character assigned to it, so where are those weird symbols creeping in from?  I'm not getting the same issues with `U+20B9 ₹ INDIAN RUPEE SIGN`, which is nearly as new and badly supported, but at least fails more gracefully.

Comment: fileformat.info now displays the character correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best shot at present is probably to use the Google font [Source Sans Pro](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro). It contains TURKISH LIRA in its latin1-subset. So you can use e.g.

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=
"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext">
<style>
body { font-family: Source Sans Pro; }
</style>
```

However, this means that you should consider using Source Sans Pro as your overall font. There are two reasons to this. Suppose that you declare `font-family: Arial, Source Sans Pro` for example. First, IE 9 fails to render the TURKISH LIRA then (it is not good at using fonts, really). Second, on browsers that use fonts technically OK, an expression like “₺50” (a number preceded by TURKISH LIRA) will look odd, since the digits are much taller than the currency sign. The reason is that in Source Sans Pro, TURKISH LIRA has been designed to match the height of digits in that font, and in Arial, digits are smaller in height.

As an alternative, you could use an image of TURKISH LIRA in a relatively large size and use `img` element to embed it, with `height` property set in `em` units to make it scale to the font size. The reason for the largish size is that images generally scale well downwards but not that well upwards. In my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html), I suggest using `height: 0.8em` for characters embedded as images, but the exact dimensioning really depends on the design of the character and the image and how it should relate to characters in a font. The normal principle is to make currency characters like “$”, “£”, and “€” occupy the same height as digits (specifically, “lining figures”, or “uppercase digits”, which is what most fonts have by default; Source Sans Pro has “oldstyle figures” too, but they need to be selected using CSS).

To put things into perspective, TURKISH LIRA is the newest character in Unicode, added last September, and it has usually taken about ten years or more from the adoption of a character into Unicode to its general availability in fonts.

P.S. This is a font issue, not a browser issue, though some browsers (IE) still have difficulties in picking up characters from different fonts.

Comment: Sounds really good otherwise, but how did you conclude that Source Sans Pro supports the lira?  I'm getting X's when I try to view the string "U+20BA ₺ TURKISH LIRA SIGN" in the Google webfonts preview.  Also, as noted above images are not an option for us, since the characters will be used in user-editable textareas.

Comment: @jpatokal, simply by testing with `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`.

Comment: A-ha! Worked it out, you need to specify `subset=latin-ext`: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: ...ja terveisia Melbournesta Tampereelle ex-oppilaaltanne silloisessa TKK:ssa, maailma on pieni ;)

Comment: @jpatokal, right, TURKISH LIRA is in latin-ext subset. My bad. I tested on a computer with Source Sans Pro installed in the system (as a version that contains latin-ext). For this reason, I was also mistaken about the presence of TURKISH LIRA in italic and bold – it is available there, too. I have corrected my answer, and I added code sample.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela _P.S. This is a font issue, not a browser issue, though some browsers (IE) still have difficulties in picking up characters from different fonts._ What exactly do you mean by this? We are eventually going to use this font, but what is the full reason why it doesn't work in IE7, but works in Firefox?

Comment: @Magnilex, the IE bug I was referring to relates to situations where the primary font does not contain a character and the browser should try to get from another font. It should not be a problem if you specify a downloadable font (as the first one in the `font-family` list), it gets used by the browser, and it contains the desired character.

Answer (score 4):

You can deliver your own font over the web via: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face and create your own font via http://fontforge.org/

If you are using XML and your requirements don't disallow it, you could use entities to define some markup which includes image markup for the time being (and could be replaced with the Unicode character later), or do something similar in HTML via [JS or CSS](https://github.com/brettz9/js-css-entities).

Answer (score 1):

I think 'do nothing' is the best idea. If the user's browser / fonts don't support it, then it's the user that needs to upgrade. Anything you do in the server side will be a hack (though delivering a font via CSS is not a bad idea). If your app supports arbitrary Unicode in user supplied text, eventually your application will become compliant, as older browsers and devices get replaced by newer ones.

Explaining this to your bosses is the hard part.